# How to format date field of input file while creating a dataset in sas

Tags: sas

My input file looks like this:

FCODE,AIRPORT,TDATE,CHILD,ADULT,ECAR,FCAR
IA06100,CDGWE,01APR2000,8,85,3328,11730
IA05900,CDG,01APR2000,8,85,2392,8415
IA07200,FRA,01APR2000,10,97,1720,5432
IA04700,LHR,01APR2000,14,120,2576,7320

I want to read this file and create a dataset, where the TDATE file is formatted into mm/dd/yyyy. The following is my base sas code:

```
data test;
  infile "C:\SAS Training\testfile.txt" firstobs=2 dlm=',';
  input FCODE $  AIRPORT $ TDATE $ CHILD ADULT ECAR FCAR;
  format tdate MMDDYYYY10.;
run;
```

But I am getting ERROR 48-59: The informat $MMDDYY was not found or could not be loaded. Essentially I want to convert the date "01APR2000" in the input file to "04/01/2000" in the dataset.

Thanks

Comment: It is best to use DSD option with delimited data.  Otherwise SAS will not interpret adjacent delimiters as indicating a missing value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below. TDATE is a date (special case of numeric in SAS) so no following $ in input statement. You also make some confusion between informat (how SAS reads raw data and convert it) and format (how SAS displays data).

```
data test;
  infile "C:\SAS Training\testfile.txt" firstobs=2 dlm=',';
  input FCODE $  AIRPORT $ TDATE CHILD ADULT ECAR FCAR;
  informat tdate DATE9.;
  format tdate DDMMYY10.;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. It resolved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proper INFORMAT

TDATE :date.

Note the :